# C# delegate in function call

Tags: c#, delegates

I have defined a delegate like this:

```
   delegate void processRecord(int a, int b);
```

now i want to use that to create an anonymous method to supply in a function call. The function is defined as such:

```
   void someFunction(processRecord fcn);
```

and I want to call `someFunction` with an anonymous method, but this I cannot get right:

```
   someFunction(new processRecord(a, b) {
       // do stuff
   });
```

How is the correct syntax for something like this?

Comment: Do you use `processRecord` delegate anywhere else? Is not - use `Action`

Comment: Yes, it is used at other places.

Comment: You can at least call it like `someFunction((a, b) => /* a and b usage*/);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it like this:

```
someFunction(delegate( int a, int b) {
   // do stuff
});
```

C# compiler will figure out that you are making a `delegate processRecord` from the context of the call.

Comment: Hm. I thought I had tried it. I try it now, and it works. Probably made a mistake in all my fiddling.

Answer (score 6):

The correct syntax to declare the call to method with `processRecord` parameter is:

```
someFunction(delegate (int a, int b) {
    // use a and b here
});
```

You can take advantage of lambda syntax invoking your `someFunction`, because `processRecord` is compatible with `Action<int,int>`,  like this:

```
someFunction((a, x) => Console.WriteLine(a + "; " + x));
```

But in .net framework there already exist generic delegate `Action` since `.NET 3.5`, which you can use instead of creating your own.

So instead you can simply define your function as

```
void someFunction(Action<int, int> fcn) {}
```

then call

```
someFunction( (a,b) => /*use a and b here*/ );
```

Comment: You don't need to use `Action` to use a lambda, you can use that lambda, exactly as you have there, with the delegate he's currently using.

Comment: @Bart - Action is a predefined delegate type for any void function with any number of parameters up to about 18 or so (not sure on that point). Unless your delegate type uses output or ref parameters, using an Action<> or Func<> like in this example is generally the way to go.

Comment: @Servy but you should somehow declare formal parameters, shouldn't you?

Comment: The Action<int,int> would allow you to not have to first define the processRecord(int,int) delegate.

Comment: @BStateham you don't need to declare your own type of `delegate` since `.net 2.0`.

Comment: @Servy Yes, of course you can also use his delegate type, but why bother defining one when you can use Action<>?

Comment: @BStateham But he's already done that.  Yes, it would allow him to delete that definition, but whether or not he does that will have *no effect* on how the anonymous method is created.  Your answer implies otherwise.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov That's not entirely true.  There are edge cases that `Action` and `Func` don't cover, although you *rarely* need to create your own delegates.  Exceptions are delegates with `params`, optional arguments, ref/out parameters, or with more than 16 parameters.

Comment: @JLRishe I'm not saying he *shouldn't* use `Action`, merely that it's not imperative that he use it.  This answer implies that it's a *requirement* and not a completely unrelated refactor.

Comment: @Servy yes, ok, agree, you don't need to declare `void` delegate with two input `Int32`, does that statement satisfies you?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Sure.  I never said that you did.  My point is that the *answer* should be irrelivant of the use of `Action`, using `Action` is just a side comment, and should be indicated as such if used in an answer.

Comment: @Servy ok, I agree, no objections.

Comment: Actually, the generic `Action<...>` delegates were introduced by .Net **3.5**.

Comment: @SLaks I always forget when generic `Action` and `Func` was introduced. `Action<T1, T2>` was in **.NET 3.5**, `Action<T>` in **.NET 2.0** - hard to remember. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use it if you use deletegate in your  `someFunction`

```
   someFunction(delegate( int a, int b) {
       // do some stuff
    });
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/JGV6XS).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options, all of which do effectively the same thing:

```
someFunction((a,b) => DoStuff());

someFunction(delegate(int a, int b){ doStuff(); });

someFunction(new processRecord((int a, int b) => 
{
    doStuff(); doMoreStuff(); 
}));
```

Comment: I'd like to add `someFunction((a,b) => { doStuff(); });`

Answer (score 0):

```
processRecord t = (q,w) =>
        {
            int n = q+w;
        };
        someFunction(t);
```